# How input boxes save previous entries

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input

Quick question here. I am creating a web app using MVC. I've noticed when I add input boxes to pages, they save previous entries in a dropdown fashion, like so:

[image: Dropdown Image]

While this IS handy, I'd like to know a couple things:

1. How/Where are these previous entries being saved? Is this my browser or an MVC thing?
2. If need be, how can I override this default behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's in your specific project, but it could be one of three things:

1. Some browsers, if you submit a form, remember the submitted values and automatically make inputs autocomplete. The `autocomplete` HTML attribute on forms and inputs can help to control that.
2. HTML 5 has a `datalist` element which lets you associate a list of options with an input, so autocomplete can be implemented manually.
3. There may be some JavaScript, potentially paired with AJAX doing this autocomplete.

Comment: I didn't know about the `datalist` element. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Im not using the autocomplete attribute, datalist element, or js/ajax. Is it safe to say its my browser?

Comment: Yes, seems most likely.